# Raspberry pi NAS and wordpress website

Tags: wordpress, raspberry-pi, nas

I have a Raspberry Pi installed with Raspian running on it. I then configured it as NAS but now I wish to host a blog on it as well. I installed Wordpress however, once finished my NAS stops to work. I can no longer see it in my network but is still accessible through SSH.

My question now is, is it possible to have a working NAS as well as run Wordpress on it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is possible (I have done it).

What you need to do is install a server such as Apache and then put your wordpress folder and the NAS web UI component (folder) in the web server root directory (you can also put a symlink there and place the folders in another location).

For the NAS, I advise using Owncloud because I have used and thus could clarify how to set it up. There are many tutorials to install Apache and other web servers such as [this one.](http://readwrite.com/2014/06/27/raspberry-pi-web-server-website-hosting)